# windbg how to unassemble instructions located inside an exported function of user32.dll

Tags: windows, assembly, windbg, disassembly

Is this possible if so please explain and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, `dumpbin /disasm user32.dll` is almost certainly an easier route the `windbg`.

Comment: @Victor: Just redirect the output to a file, like: `dumpbin /disasm user32.dll > user32.asm`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to get the command above working directing the output to a file. I do have one more question how come can you can run a command like u nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile under Windbg and it will unassemble the first few instructions located at the address of NtDeviceIOControl in memory ? By default its using ntdll.dll. Can I change this to user32.dll somehow ? Is this possible ?

Comment: @Victor: I'm pretty sure it's possible, but it's been long enough since I had to that I don't remember how.

Comment: Thanks to both replies. I was able to get the command under Windbg working as follows "u user32!GetWindowDC" without the quotes and it gave me the results I was looking for. I was able to compare the opcodes with the dumpbin output and they matched up. GetWindowDC was just an example but I wanted to find out if it possible to do this. Thanks so much again. Best Regards